# jQuery & Ajax: one click triggers two event and updates two div's

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-app-engine

I am working on Google App engine with Python. I have a web page in which there are a `login` div and a `menu` div. I'd like that when a user successfully logs in, the system will display a greeting message in the `login` div, and at the same time the items in the `menu` div will be adjusted according to the user's privilege. The template engine is also used for updating div's.

The codes are as follows:

HTML:

```
...
<div id="loginDiv">
  {% if not loggedIn %}
    <form class="loginSubmitForm" action="/login" method="post">
      Account: <input type="text" name="account" /><br />
      Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
    </form>
  {% else %}
    {{gretingMessage}}
  {% endif %}
</div>

...

<div id="menuDiv">
  {% if privlige1 %}
    some items
  {% else %} {% if previlige2 %}
    other items
  {% endif %} {% endif %}
</div>

...
```

jQuery:

```
// Login submit form
$('.loginSubmitForm').ajaxForm({
  success: function(returnData) {
    $('#loginDiv').html(returnData);
  }
});
```

My question: how do I trigger two events and update the two div's with only one login click?

Comment: You just need to add more to the success function. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: You mean there are two statements in success? Like the following: `$('#loginDiv').html(returnData); $('#menudiv').html(data2);` How do I insert the content of `data2`. Also, how do I arrange the sever-side programs?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. Your server-side question is too vague. Give it a try and ask a specific question about what's not working.